# Drools get WorkingMemory to see facts in DRL

Tags: java, jboss, rules, drools

How can I get the WorkingMemory to know about the facts written in the DRL? Currently, the facts declared in the DRL do not exist in the WorkingMemory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DRL only **describes** facts and rules, you have to inject facts into working memory by yourself. In RHS you can inject new facts in WM but for order rule engine to reach your RHS, it needs some objects already injected and matched against LHS.

Comment: It turns out I was having MASSIVE issues with Observer patterns. Sorry for being a muppet

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your `KnowledgeSession`/`WorkingMemory`:

```
knowledgeSession.addEventListener(new DebugWorkingMemoryEventListener());
```

Comment: It still does not recognise anything from my DRL

Comment: Must be because you didn't insert any facts in the the WM :)

Comment: @GeoffreyDeSmet PLease see this question. I am unable to fix it out. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20158726/dialect-error-message-drool
Thanks for your time.